# nginx to proxy ELK

Tags: nginx, kibana, reverse-proxy, elastic-stack

I'm trying to proxy a backend server running ELK. Here's my environment info:

```
root@proxy:~#
root@proxy:~# cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
root@proxy:~#
root@proxy:~# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
root@proxy:~#
root@proxy:~# cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
events {
        worker_connections 768;
}
http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        gzip on;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
root@proxy:~#
root@proxy:~# cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/elk.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.tld;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name domain.tld;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /elk {
        proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
        proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    }
}
root@proxy:~#
```

With the above configurations, when I go to https://domain.tld, I can view my static site without issues but when I go to https://domain.tld/elk, I get a 404 Not Found. Here's the Raw Data of the 404:

```
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}
```

Here's the Headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 04 Jan 2019 11:42:55 GMT
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
cache-control: no-cache
content-encoding: gzip
kbn-name: kibana
kbn-xpack-sig: d39f386737f81acb1fe7cc2cc4d80109
vary: accept-encoding

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Host: domain.tld
Referer: https://domain.tld/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0
```

If I make my config as this:

```
root@proxy:~# cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/elk.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.tld;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name domain.tld;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
        proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    }
}
root@proxy:~#
```

and go to https://domain.tld, it will proxy back to ELK correctly and the Kibana dashboard loads properly.

Been tinkering around, researched online and adjusted the samples accordingly but cannot make it to work the way I wanted. Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: This is a guess, but you probably need to tell Kibana that it's root is at `/elk` and not `/`. Otherwise it might be trying to access resources at the root, these requests would likely be handled by nginx and return 404 errors.

Comment: Thank you, kristaps. Your comment made sense after reading (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-and-nginx-in-subpath/90280) - this led me to figure out the answer which @kahveci mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to make two changes to solve the issue. First, please add slashes at the end of `location` and `proxy_pass` directive in Nginx server block file as follows:

```
location /elk/ {
        proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:5601/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
        proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
}
```

Second, please uncomment `server.basePath` setting and give the value of `/elk` in **kibana.yml** config file:

```
server.basePath: "/elk"
```

Finally, you must restart both Nginx and Kibana before giving it another try.